# Checking if set of elements can jointly create parent element

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a dictionary with all elements and their children.

For example, looking at the python dictionary below:

```
product_dict = {
        'A': {'B', 'C', 'D'},
        'B': {'E', 'F'},
        'C': {'G'},
        'D': {},
        'E': {'H', 'I'}
    }
```

By the dict we can infer that, for example:

- B, C and D create A.
- E, F, G and D also create A.
- H, I, F, G and D also create A, etc...

What would be the best way to create a function that would return if any given set of elements can create another element, i.e. Can {'H','I','F','G','D'} create'A'?

I am using Python and I think recursion would be the best way to crack this problem but, being a newbie in it myself, I am open to any other types of algorithms which would help me solve this case.

Comment: Your `product_dict` appears to be a tree in this example. What if it was a directed acyclic graph, but not a tree? For instance `product_dict = {'A': {'B', 'C'}, 'B': {'D'}, 'C': {'D'}}`. Now `'B'` and `'C'` can both be produced by `'D'`. Now would you say that `'D'` alone is enough to produce `'A'`, or do you need two occurrences of `'D'`?

Comment: @Stef Unfortunately I do not think it is. They are all independent elements at that 'level of depth', meaning, that D would not create B nor C, but the 3 together would create A.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is indeed natural for this, since we're essentially exploring the branches of a tree.

The recurrence formula is roughly: "The target is already in the resources; or all of the children of the target can be produced recursively from these resources".

Important note: you have `'D': {}` in your dict, which means that `'D'` can be created from nothing. This is very different from not having `'D'` in the dict, which would have meant that `'D'` cannot be created.

```py
product_dict = {
        'A': {'B', 'C', 'D'},
        'B': {'E', 'F'},
        'C': {'G'},
        'D': {},
        'E': {'H', 'I'}
    }

def can_create(target, resources, product_dict=product_dict):
    return (
        (target in resources) or
        (
            target in product_dict and
            all(can_create(child, resources, product_dict)
                for child in product_dict[target])
        )
    )

for resources in map(set, ('A', 'B', 'BCD', 'EFGD', 'HIFG', 'HIFGD')):
    result = can_create('A', resources)
    print('{:25s} {} create A'.format(str(resources), 'can' if result else 'cannot'))

del product_dict['D']
print('\nNow we remove D from the dict and try again.\n')

for resources in map(set, ('A', 'B', 'BCD', 'EFGD', 'HIFG', 'HIFGD')):
    result = can_create('A', resources)
    print('{:25s} {} create A'.format(str(resources), 'can' if result else 'cannot'))
```

Output:

```
{'A'}                     can create A
{'B'}                     cannot create A
{'D', 'C', 'B'}           can create A
{'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'}      can create A
{'I', 'F', 'H', 'G'}      can create A
{'D', 'H', 'I', 'F', 'G'} can create A

Now we remove D from the dict and try again.

{'A'}                     can create A
{'B'}                     cannot create A
{'D', 'C', 'B'}           can create A
{'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'}      can create A
{'I', 'F', 'H', 'G'}      cannot create A
{'D', 'H', 'I', 'F', 'G'} can create A
```

Comment: Was just about to post my `can_make` function which bears a striking resemblance to your `can_create`... :)

Comment: @Nick Well, I don't claim to be original - there's only so many ways to recursively explore a tree. There is room for improvement though - consider the case of a directed acyclic graph like `product_dict = {'A': {'B', 'C'}, 'B': {'D'}, 'C': {'D'}}`. My function would answer that `{'D'}` can create `'A'`, although intuitively we should need two occurrences of `'D'`.

Comment: Yeah, that's an interesting question, and certainly would need a different approach. But in the manner OP has described their problem, I think this is the correct solution

Comment: It does seem to be working perfectly, thank you so much this, such a great code example to understand recursion!