# Checking which set of elements can jointly create parent element

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, recursion

This question is an extension of a previous one I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75532329/checking-if-set-of-elements-can-jointly-create-parent-element).

I have a dictionary that contains some items and their children:

```
product_dict = {
        'A': {'B', 'C', 'D'},
        'B': {'E', 'F'},
        'C': {'G'},
        'E': {'H', 'I'}
    }
```

By the dict we can infer that, for example:

- B, C and D create A.
- E, F, G and D also create A.
- H, I, F, G and D also create A
- D cannot be created.

I already know how, provided a given set of resources, if they can, when combined, add up to a target. E.g. If I was given B as the target and E, F and G as the resources I know that B could be created, because B is parent to E and F and they are a subset of the resources.

However, how would I be able to know which products of the resources are being used? In the example below I'd like the function to return a list containing E and F, excluding G because G had nothing to do with the creation of B.

The function I'm using is:

```
def can_create(target, resources, product_dict=product_dict, used_resources=None):
    if used_resources is None:
        used_resources = []
    
    if target in resources:
        used_resources.append(target)
        return used_resources
    
    if target in product_dict:
        for child in product_dict[target]:
            used_resources = can_create(child, resources, product_dict, used_resources)

    return used_resources
```

Which is returning the subset of resources that can create the target however not as group. To illustrate, B is created by E and F. If the target is B and the resources are E, F and G, the function correctly returns a list of E and F. However, if the resources are only F and G it will return a list containing F and ideally it would return an empty list because we don't have all the necessary elements to create tge target.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the construction of the set succeeds. Assuming that you may start with non-empty `used_resources` variable. If you do not need to keep track of the original value, you can replace

```
def can_create(target, resources, product_dict=product_dict, used_resources=None):
    if used_resources is None:
        used_resources = []
    initial_used_resources = used_resources.copy()
    
    if target in resources:
        used_resources.append(target)
        return used_resources
    
    if target in product_dict:
        for child in product_dict[target]:
            used_resources = can_create(child, resources, product_dict, used_resources)
        if used_resources != target:
            used_resources = initial_used_resources
            #some error handling if needed
    return used_resources
```

If you do not need to keep track of the original value, you can replace `used_resources = initial_used_resources` with `used_resources = []` and get rid of `initial_used_resources = used_resources.copy()` line

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it does not seem to be working